# Como posso fazer uma máscara de e-mail com PHP?

Tags: php, email

Como eu faço uma máscara de e-mail com PHP mostrando algumas letras, todos os números e caracteres especiais? Ex: stackoverflow2015-brasil@hotmail.com deveria ficar assim: stack_______2015-_____@__tmail.com

Comment: Mascara ou validação do formato?

Comment: @rray mascara mesmo. Eu pego ele completo e retorno do jeito que está na descrição da pergunta. O meu objetivo é ocultar alguns caracteres ao mostrar o e-mail ao usuário

Comment: qual o padrão de máscara deseja aplicar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei essa função abaixo, pois reparei que o padrão que você precisa não seria fácil apenas com expressões regulares.

```
    <?php 

 function mascara($email){

// vamos separar a string em 2 partes com explode

$mascara = explode("@", $email);

$part1Email = $mascara[0];
$part2Email = $mascara[1];

/* 

PARTE 1 DA STRING:

*/

    $quantidadeCarac = strlen($part1Email); 
    //calcula quantos caracteres tem na primeira parte da string

    $inicio = $quantidadeCarac / 4; 
    // não vamos alterar o começo, então iremos separa-lo da string

    $inicioString = substr($part1Email, 0, $inicio); 
    // fazemos a separação do inicio

    $restanteString = str_replace($inicioString, "", $part1Email); 
    // pegaremos o restante 

    $restanteString = preg_replace( "/[^0-9_-]/", "_", $restanteString); 
    // vamos substituir tudo que não for numeros por "_"


/* 

PARTE 2 DA STRING:

*/

    $quantidadeCarac2 = strlen($part2Email); 
    // calcula quantos caracteres tem na segunda parte da string

    $finalParte2 = substr($part2Email, 2, $quantidadeCarac2); 
    // vamos separar a parte final que não será alterada

    $inicioParte2 = str_replace($finalParte2, "", $part2Email); 
    // separamos o começo

    $inicioParte2 = preg_replace( "/[^0-9_-]/", "_", $inicioParte2); 
    // alteramos o começo


// finaliza a string juntando as partes

$mascaraNova = $inicioString.$restanteString."@".$inicioParte2.$finalParte2;

return $mascaraNova;

}

 $string = "stackoverflow2015-brasil@hotmail.com";

 $string = mascara($string);

 echo $string;

 ?>
```

Ele retorna isso:

> **stacko_______2015-______@__tmail.com**

com o email: geofilipe98pe75@maquina.com.br

Ele retorna isso:

> **geo______98__75@__quina.com.br**